# How to get the length of row/column of multidimensional array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

How do I get the length of a row or column of a multidimensional array in C#?

for example:

```
int[,] matrix = new int[2,3];

matrix.rowLength = 2;
matrix.colLength = 3;
```

Comment: Wouldn't there be 2 rows and 3 columns?

Answer (score 205, accepted):

```
matrix.GetLength(0)  -> Gets the first dimension size

matrix.GetLength(1)  -> Gets the second dimension size
```

Answer (score 21):

Have you looked at the properties of an `Array`?

- `Length` gives you the length of the array (total number of cells).
- `GetLength(n)` gives you the number of cells in the specified dimension (relative to 0). If you have a 3-dimensional array:

  ```
  int[,,] multiDimensionalArray = new int[21,72,103] ;
  ```

  then `multiDimensionalArray.GetLength(n)` will, for n = 0, 1 and 2, return 21, 72 and 103 respectively.

If you're constructing Jagged/sparse arrays, then the problem is somewhat more complicated. Jagged/sparse arrays are [usually] constructed as a nested collection of arrays within arrays. In which case you need to examine each element in turn. These are usually nested 1-dimensional arrays, but there is not reason you couldn't have, say, a 2d array containing 3d arrays containing 5d arrays.

In any case, with a jagged/sparse structure, you need to use the length properties on each cell.

Answer (score 10):

for 2-d array use this code :

```
var array = new int[,]
{
    {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 },
    {11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20 }
};
var row = array.GetLength(0);
var col = array.GetLength(1);
```

output of code is :

- row = 2
- col = 10

for n-d array syntax is like above code:

```
var d1 = array.GetLength(0);   // size of 1st dimension
var d2 = array.GetLength(1);   // size of 2nd dimension
var d3 = array.GetLength(2);   // size of 3rd dimension
.
.
.
var dn = array.GetLength(n-1);   // size of n dimension
```

Best Regards!

Answer (score 2):

Use `matrix.GetLowerBound(0)` and `matrix.GetUpperBound(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:
matrix.GetUpperBound(0);//rows
matrix.GetUpperBound(1);//columns

Comment: The question is tagged c#, not visual basic.