# I have a loop on C# in array but it does not work as well

Tags: c#

this is the error that I get now:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arrDate.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(arrDate[i, 0]);            
}
```

the error message is:**Index out of range exception was unhandled.**

this is the array:

```
string[,] arrDate = new string[2, 3];
arrDate[0, 0] = "10/05/2017";
arrDate[0, 1] = "15/05/2017";
arrDate[0, 2] = "mily";
arrDate[1, 0] = "20/05/2017";
arrDate[1, 1] = "22/05/2017";
arrDate[1, 2] = "many";
```

this question is different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404683/get-a-length-of-row-column-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Show how you have declared and initialized that _arrDate_ variable

Comment: dear steve i have added it

Answer (score 4):

The [Length](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.array.length(v=vs.110).aspx) property of a multidimensional array gives the total amount of elements. Imagine you have a two dimensional 2 x 3, then length returns 2 x 3 = 6.

You code tries to iterate about 6 rows (in this example) and would raise an exception while trying to access the third row (`i = 2`).

Please try

```
for(int i = 0; i < arrDate.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(arrDate[i, 0]);            
}
```

`GetLength(0)` returns the length of the first dimension.

Comment: thanks it worked for me now