# Delete Specific Column Row Multidimensional Array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

1. Hi can someone help me deleting array in multidimensional this code keeps on Array out of Bound

   ````
   ```
   int[,] Arr = {
     { 10,20,30,40},
     { 10,20,30,40},
     { 10,20,30,40}, 
     { 10,20,30,40}
   };

   int index = 1;
   for(int x = 0; x <= 3; x++) { 
       for (int i = index; i < Arr.Length - 1; i++)
       {

           Arr[i, x] = Arr[i + 1, x];


       }
   }
   ```
   ````

Comment: Once an array is initialized it is fixed - so how are you planning on deleting from it? For which values of `i` and `x` are you getting the exception?

Comment: Arr[i, x] = Arr[i + 1, x];  i think the x is the problem . i want to delete a specific row

Comment: Use a list instead of an array : List<Listint>> Arr = new List<List<int>>() {
  new List<int>() { 10,20,30,40},
  new List<int>() { 10,20,30,40},
  new List<int>() { 10,20,30,40}, 
  new List<int>() { 10,20,30,40}
};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Length` property returns the length of the first dimension. When you want to access the other dimensions, you have to use the `GetLength()` method. See [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9404722/696355).